# Multivariate Path Construction using Sobol numbers

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, simulation

I am sharing my code,which I have tried to perform as per the instruction mentioned below. Please correct it so that I could get my output.

Instruction:
Use the first m dimensions of the Sobol vector of length (m*n) to build the realisations of m uncorrelated diffusions `W_{i}(T)` for i=1..m, the next m for the realisations `W_{i}(T/2)` and so on.

Having all the values `W_{i,k}` for `i=1..m` and `k=1..n`, with j representing the time point `(k*ΔT)` with `ΔT:=T/n`, subtract along time to obtain increments  `ΔW_{i}( from k-1 to k ).`

Compute a spectral decomposition of the single-step covariance matrix C over a single time step ΔT. The elements of this single step matrix are

```
 c_{ij} :=  σ_i * ρ_ij * σ_j * ΔT.
```

The matrices S and Λ such that `C = S*Λ*S^T`, the spectral-split matrix A you need is given by `A := S*sqrt(Λ),` where sqrt(Λ) is the diagonal matrix Λ of (non-negative) eigenvalues.

Code : This is for 20paths of 200 timesteps each . 
Note: Wiener process covariance is min{i,j}

```
m=20; 
soboldata= BlockRandom[ SeedRandom[ Method -> {"MKL", Method -> {"Sobol", "Dimension" -> 20}}]; 
  RandomReal[1, {200, 20}]]


mat= Table[min[i,j],{i,1,20},{j,1,200}];
mat//matrix form 

mat= C

cov=CrM[C]; 
vars=Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, m}];
lab=Table["Ito Plot No " <> ToString[i], {i, m}];

ip=ItoProcess[{soboldata},t,cov];

path=RandomFunction[ip,{0,1,0.05},10,Method->"Milstein"]; Evaluate@Table[ListLinePlot[path["PathComponent", i], PlotRange -> All,PlotLabel->lab[[i]],ImageSize->150],{i,m}]
```

Comment: What is CrM in your code?

Comment: CrM is like this CrM[m,-0.01,0.015]  . You can get an idea here         m=20; 
drift=RandomReal[{0.003,0.01},m]; 
iv=RandomReal[{0.02,0.05},m]; 
cov=CrM[m,-0.01,0.015];

Comment: U have not defined CrM[..]........just getting CrM[....] in the output..

Comment: Maybe you plan to use the inbuilt function, Covariance?

Comment: @Michael .Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @thils yes. anyway you can replace the Covaraince matrix as per your choice using  other matrix.